# How can you change duplicates of tuples in a list in python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

If you have 4 lists and zip them to a list in Python you get list with 4 tuples.For ex:

```
a=['0','0','2','3','7','6']
b=['4','4','4','5','6','7']
c=[2,2,3,4,5,5]
m=['m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6']
g=(zip(a,b,c,m))
```

Where `g =`[`('0', '4', 2, 'm1'), ('0', '4', 2, 'm2'), ('2', '4', 3, 'm3'), ('3', '5', 4, 'm4'), ('7', '6', 5, 'm5'), ('6', '7', 5, 'm6')]`. 
The first two elements are strings and the third one is a number.The 4th element always will be different.
I need assistance to find the duplicates in g with same first three elements and add some small decimal to the third element of the tuple to make them differ. For ex:

```
g=[('0', '4', 2.001, 'm1'), ('0', '4', 2.002, 'm2'), ('2', '4', 3, 'm3'), ('3', '5', 4, 'm4'), ('7', '6', 5.001, 'm5'), ('6', '7', 5.002, 'm6')]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Does the output order of the tuples matter?  Or is the only requirement that they're unique at the end?

Comment: technically `'2' != 2` so they are different. I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I tried sets and iteration trough the list but I can even list the duplicates. I am fairly new to python.

Comment: @ mgilson yes it does matter the order of the output, as this will be my inout in another code I have to keep them in the form of the list g.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen they represent different things. The numbers in a string represent vertices and the numbers as a third element represent weight of edges between them (Graph theory). Thus they do not have the same meaning. I am trying to distinguish the same weigh of the edges (the third element of the tuple) between the same vertices ( the first two elements of the tuple).

Comment: @Oli In that case, you should have included whatever you have tried. The community responds positively to such efforts! :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list and use `enumerate` to keep track of the indice, when you find one with duplicates change the value at that indice:

```
for i, tup in enumerate(g):
    if str(tup[2]) in tup[:2]:
        g[i][2]+=0.01
```